# ggmap: apply specific color to value after applying gradient scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, viridis

I'd like to be able to use a gradient to fill the colors on a map, but I need specific values (like zero) to be a specific color (say, red or grey).

Is there some way to first apply the gradient, and then set these specific color values?  I'd like to be able to do it for multiple specific values if possible.

In the example below, how could we make the 0 values red?

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(ggmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(viridis))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(albersusa)) #devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/albersusa")

us <- usa_composite()
us_map <- fortify(us, region="name") %>% 
  rename(state = id)


dat <- tibble(state = state.name, value = sample(-2:5, 50, replace = T))

dat %>% 
  right_join(us_map) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = value, group = group), color = "white", size = .2) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  scale_fill_viridis()
#> Joining, by = "state"
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can change `0` to `NA` in your plot data object and within `scale_fill_viridis` use argument `na.value`:

```
# Create plot data object
pd <- right_join(dat, us_map)
# Replace wanted value with NA
pd$value[pd$value == 0] <- NA

ggplot(pd, aes(long, lat, fill = value, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(color = "white", size = 0.2) +
    coord_fixed(1.3) +
    scale_fill_viridis(na.value = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of `na.value`, but I am using it for NAs.